# Non-root Android full phone backup

Tags: android, backup

Since I have [some problems migrating my whole data from Android 7.1 down to Android 6.0](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/193911/20449) and since using system-built solutions seems to be not working in this scenario, I'm looking for any full-phone backup for Android 6.0 and 70 that does not need a root.

By full phone backup I mean:

- Google account,
- phone and system settings,
- all apps settings (+ recreation of installed apps on destination phone),
- all user files (i.e. media).

Is such application even possible? Is it possible to backup and restore entire phone without root access?

Comment: Afraid such an app is impossible without root, as no normal app gets the necessery access (one app cannot access data from another). The closest you can come to this is an ADB backup, but that's also nor really complete. A real full backup will need full access, hence root.

Comment: The ADB backup idea sounds like a great answer to this question. Agreed that this is not a complete backup, but still this is as far as I can go with no-root phone. Consider rewriting this to an answer (maybe optionally providing some steps like [here](https://www.technipages.com/how-to-backup-your-entire-android-device), [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/backup-restore-your-android-phone-using-adb-ajibola-okubanjo/) or [here](https://9to5google.com/2017/11/04/how-to-backup-restore-android-device-data-android-basics/)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A full backup app is impossible without root access, as it cannot access the data of other apps (and neither some system data like WiFi APs etc). The closest you can get to that is **ADB backup** – details on that (and some helpers) are described on our Android sister site: [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575).

To use ADB's backup feature you will need parts of the Android SDK. Not the full SDK, but at least some essential elements – details again can be found on our sister site: [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575). For more details on ADB, also see the [adb tag-wiki there](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info).

As for apps to perform this directly on the device, to my knowledge there's only *Helium* (see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/37738/16575)), which unfortunately seems no longer to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using one app for [Backup & Restore Data Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fazconapps.backup.restore.data&hl=en_US&gl=FR) and it's working great. The app is responsive and user interface is also good. As far as backing up everything without rooting, that's not possible as the app doesn't have necessary permissions without root. But you can backup other data and then transfer them to new phone by using the same app.